# add controls (Picturebox) in loop

Tags: c#

**What i have:**  Big PictureBox (lets call it Pic_Map) on the form. A class `Ore.cs`, A `List<Ore> ores;` and a database that pulls the data and places it into the `ores` list.

**Functionality:**  So, The functionality of this is i have a TextBox/Combobox and a Button. When i press the Button, it will loop through the `ores` list and Dynamically add PictureBoxes ontop of the Pic_Map based on TexBox/ComboBox being equal to the data (in this case Ore_Name).

**Problem:**  This all works fine, but the problem is that when i add the PictureBoxes Dynamically, it only seems to add the last value on the `ores` list (Red circles on Pic_Map). so, it ends up showing only 1 PictureBox instead of lets say 3, since i have 3 value Names that match with the TextBox/ComboBox.

**Question:**  How to get it to work like when i write/choose "Flame Stone" it looks on all the data that has "Flame Stone" in its name and add it (Instead of it adding only the last value from the list).

**Code:**

```
private void PopulateComboBoxByName()
    {
        PictureBox ore_Area = new PictureBox(); 

        db.GetOre(); //Getting data and putting it into "ores" list

        foreach (Ore ore in db.ores)
        {
            if (CBOX_Filter.SelectedItem.ToString() == ore.Ore_Name)
            {
                int area_Width = Convert.ToInt32(ore.Area_Width);
                int area_Height = Convert.ToInt32(ore.Area_Height);

                int ore_Width = Convert.ToInt32(ore.Ore_Width);
                int ore_Height = Convert.ToInt32(ore.Ore_Height) - area_Height / 2;
                ore_Area.Name = "ore_Area";

                ore_Area.ImageLocation = @"Data\Images\Circle.png";
                ore_Area.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                ore_Area.Size = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(area_Width), Convert.ToInt32(area_Height));
                ore_Area.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(ore_Width), Convert.ToInt32(ore_Height));
                ore_Area.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

                this.Controls.Add(ore_Area);
            }
        }

        ore_Area.Parent = PIC_Map;
    }
```

**Images:**

***Data:***
[image: Data]

***Map:***
[image: Dynamic Picturebox (red circle)]

Comment: Could the Location always the same?

Comment: Yea, basicly "Image_Width" and "Image_Height" are the coordinates for the form to place the pictureboxes. so location, etc can be the same that doesn't matter.

Comment: You are only creating one PictureBox,

Comment: But it does the foreach loop, or does that not count? how can i fix it so it adds all the pictureboxes?

Comment: You are making one PictureBox before the loop.  Move that line to inside the loop.  Remove the `ore_Area.Parent = PIC_Map;` line, too.  Change `this.Controls.Add` to `PIC_Map.Controls.Add`

Comment: You may also want to look in to using GDI to draw directly on your map, instead of using `PictureBox`.  Depending on how many "things" you have to draw to the map this way, you could see significant performance improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to LarsTech, it has been fixed.

Making the picturebox is moved inside the loop, `this.controls.add` is changed to `PIC_Map.controls.add` and `Ore_Area.Parent = PIC_Map;` is deleted.